# Angular 4 parsing html with ngmodel

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am having some an issue with parsing a string in my view which has `br` tags that is bound using `ngModel` for example,

Here is my string

```
this.customer_address = this.customer.customer_name + '<br>' +
        this.customer.address.street + '<br>' + this.customer.address.postcode + '<br>' + this.customer.address.country;
```

and here is what I have in my HTML,

```
 <md-input-container class="example-full-width">
        <textarea [readonly]="invoice.lock || invoice.lock_archive" mdInput placeholder="Billing Address" name="address" [(ngModel)]="customer_address">

        </textarea>
      </md-input-container>
```

This seems to print the `br` tags within the textarea however I would like to escape them but I would also like to keep them when I am saving the object for example, when a new line is added I a `br` tag is added. I am not sure what best options.

Comment: Do you want HTML tags to be visible inside the textarea?, and then when you save it, it will be saved including the `<br>` tags? Can you explain what you want to work up on to?

Comment: They, no I don't want the HTML the html tag to be visible on the page. So the `<br>` tags will be escaped and the user will just see a new break line, however when the user adds a new line it will add the break line just not to the view, hopefully that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to use a simple CSS property of `white-space: pre-line;` which preserves the white spaces on the text area. So my data is saved as 

`some text \n\n line break`

so in my bank-end I do a simple replace of `\n` with `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add the `<br>` to the text area value (so it will be visible to the user) you can just add the text to the inside of the textarea element:

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
    <textarea [readonly]="invoice.lock || invoice.lock_archive" mdInputplaceholder="Billing Address" name="address" [(ngModel)]="customer_address">
        {{customer_address}}
    </textarea>
  </md-input-container>
```

In this case, the `<br>` tags will be visible so the user will see the following value inside the textarea:

> John Doe <br> 123 Broadway <br> 12345 NY <br> USA

In case you want your text to be *beautiful* to the user, you can add this to the property `innerHTML` of the element. So you could do the following:

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
    <textarea [readonly]="invoice.lock || invoice.lock_archive" mdInputplaceholder="Billing Address" name="address" [(ngModel)]="customer_address" [innerHTML]="customer_address">

    </textarea>
  </md-input-container>
```

In this case the address is compiled as HTML and will look as follows:

> John Doe 
>  123 Broadway 
>  12345 NY 
>  USA

You can also add the brackets to the visual of a page by using the 'ampersand element' like follows:

`&lt;` = `<` 
`&gt;` = `>`

I think this is a better way and I think it is actually a best practice. 
I Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for you help, but unfortunately this did not work for me as adding, `[innerHTML]="customer_address"` just returned `Jim's Car wash&lt;br&gt;Street<br>PO BOX<br>UK` even when adding `&lt;`, not sure why this isn't working for me.

Comment: If you do `[innerHTML]` and it shows the text as `&lt;br&gt;`, then you dont have actual brackets as text, but only the ampersand elements. Angular automatically sanitizes your data if you put it in the page, so you are not allowed to have any elements that support scripts in your page. In case of `<br>` you are allowed to use it, and using `[innerHTML]` should thus allow this.